# Register php script not returning response

Tags: php, android

I have a register form in my Android application, I first made the register/login page and everything worked just fine.

Just before I wanted to go live, I checked everything and noticed that when I registered, i'm not returning to the loginscreen. I checked logcat and it showed me the following error:

> Register Response: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /var/www/domain/app/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php on line 46

So i checked my PHP script and noticed that it is giving the error on $stmt->bind_result($email);

```
 /**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        //$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

PHP ain't my strongest side, but i'm almost 100% certain that this worked about 1 and a half month ago. What could the problem be?

FYI:

This is the location where the registration is processed in the application:

```
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
```

Comment: I don't know that this is necessarily the error, but you are binding both a prepared parameter and the result to the same variable. That is confusing and potentially a problem for your script, given that both `$stmt->bind_result($email);` and `$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);` bind by reference

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Could this become a problem later? We are not using this information yet, but we are planning on making an 2.0 later this year where we need the registration. We just want people to register now. Is there a easy fix for now?